# Rails: Find array of related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

This is the code I currently have:

```
project_ids = ProjectEnrollment.unscoped.where(user: self).pluck(:project_id)
Project.where(id: project_ids)
```

I'm sure there has to be a better way. Thanks!

Edit: I'm already using the method from the has_many relationship, with scoped projects for another case.

Answer (score 1):

In your User model:

```
has_many :project_enrollments, -> { unscoped }
has_many :projects, through: :project_enrollments
```

In your ProjectEnrollment model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

Then you can do

`user.projects`

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could have been clearer on my question, I'll edit. I'm already using the scoped method for something else. 

But this is definitely on the right track.